# Component reuse in common module

Tags: java

I have two components in a Java EE web application. These components differ only on two to three fields. Both perform the same action i.e. save data in the database and send some mail. What would be a better way to implement them? Currently I have two options:

1. Have a common vo, pass base class to service and dao layer, then based on the object type do the necessary actions in the DAO class as both the modules' data sit in two different tables.
2. Have common interfaces, common vo but a separate service and DAO.

Can anybody let me know what is better and why or if there is a better way?

Comment: What is a module? That's not a Java term.

Comment: That might depend on what the differences are. If it's only the fields and tables, you might want to use two different entities with a common mapped super class and a common service/dao.

Comment: Does my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18134502/correct-pattern-for-two-classes-that-act-similar-and-have-duplicate-code/18134611#18134611 help?

Answer (score 0):

looks like you need to use a simply abstract class, you can write the common code in this class and declare some abstract methods that subclass specific is.

Answer (score 0):

Create a common module contains `interface` of all common behaviors like `API` and made separate project for implementation of those. you can use `maven` and it is better to create a `jar` from that base module and provided that as a dependency to implementation project.